# Tiling/Caching Image Services with ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server, tiles, cache

The company I work for uses online map services while working with our clients.  We publish map documents as well as image services and have had no issues until recent.

We are able to publish/create a service for map documents containing vector data only with no issues but are now having issues with our raster services.  We are having two seperate problems:

1 - We have geodatabases with raster mosaics of LiDAR data which we can successfully publish however they will not tile/cache; and

2 - We have a geodatabase with a raster mosaic of imagery which we can't publish or tile.  When publishing we get the error "Packaging Succeeded, Publishing Failed"

I've tried to do run both situations from various computers in the office as well as directly off the server and nothing seems to work.  This issue only started a few weeks ago.

Any suggestions on what might be the issue?

Comment: What version on ArcGIS? Sounds like 10.1 or 10.2, you will want to make sure when you are doing your publish that you have enough open space for the data to copy; or that you have the Data Store paths configured properly for the common data.

Comment: We are running 10.1 and according to the properties on the server we have enough free disk space.  I'll check the data store paths, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to make sure that ArcGIS Server is running as the correct user and that the ArcGIS directories have the correct permissions. The Windows version comes with a "Configure ArcGIS Server Account" tool that will check / fix those things automatically.